# getting an image from static/img into a template in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project with a static/img folder I want to get this image loaded but since it's in a variable and static points to my static folder, not static/img I'm not sure how to get it in. I tried f'img/{project.image}'

I'm iterating through projects so 
project.image is set to equal "some_image_for_this_project.jpg" in my database

`<img class="card-img-top" src="{% static project.image %}">`

Comment: Please add some details to your question: STATIC_ROOT, STATIC_URL settings, project.image value example (it's not clear whether it contains path or not).

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but this is how it should work:

```
<img src="{% static 'images/' %}{{ project.image }}>
```

Comment: im iterating through project models so the image name is stored in project.image and I'm having trouble getting that part into the string

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help

1.) Youre template.html

```
{% load static %}
{% static 'img/name_img.jpg' %}
```

*This solution works for the directory structure

```
app
/__pycache__
/migrations
/templates
/static/img/[YOURE_FILES...]
__init__.py
[...]
```